# CakePHP 3.2, date output

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I´ve several dates wich are stored in my database like this: 2016-02-17.

I want them to be displayed like this: 17.02.2016.

For this I use this code in my AppController:

```
I18n::locale('de-DE');
Time::$defaultLocale = 'de-DE';
Time::setToStringFormat('dd.MM.YYYY');
Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('dd.MM.YYYY');
```

But my output always looks like this: 17.02.16.

How do I force the output of the year with 4 characters?

Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: just a guess: try `'dd.MM.yyyy'`

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting This might also help.

Comment: Thanks guys, but nothing´s work. :(

Comment: So you are talking about `DATE` columns, not `DATETIME`?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `date("d.m.Y", strtotime($yourDateAsStringFromDb))`. This will return the date formatted as you describe you want it.

I just tryed using this and it works to display the date as you asked.
bare in mind in this capital letters matter